# how to get latest second row in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

can anyone help me I'm new to django so I don't know how to make sql queries into django code.
my sql table is :
`select * from mangazones.mangabank_comic_banks;` 
the table image:
[sql table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcNRg.png)

then for second row query :

```
WITH added_row_number AS (SELECT comic_chapter,comic_english_name_id, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY comic_english_name_id ORDER BY comic_chapter DESC) AS row_num FROM mangazones.mangabank_comic_banks) SELECT * FROM added_row_number WHERE row_num = 2;
```

I get table:
[seond row table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQQga.png)

I want second row table query in django also.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Maybe ***`ModelClass.objects.all().order_by("-pk")[1]`***?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest or latest 2nd value in Django model:

If you want to filter using primary key:

```
latest_second = Model_Name.objects.filter().order_by('-pk')[1]
```

If you have created date and time you can do it such way:

```
latest_second = Model_Name.objects.filter().order_by('-created')[1]
```

here, `filter()` is for filtering certain items.

if you don't want to filter items then you can use:

```
latest_second = Model_Name.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[1]
```

Comment: Also ensure you wrap this in *try: except:* incase the queryset is empty.